# C linked lists grouping values

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have a problem in C linked lists. The problem is;
User will enter some inputs. And we gonna add to linked list the values. Values are, id,name,surname. My job here grouping the same ones digit and sorting them most found. Like this:

User entered:

```
47 Max Clark
37 Amy Jhinar
89 Bob Lewis
25 Jackson Adams
29 Jackie Kitcher
27 Karen Robinson
```

The list should be like this:

```
47 Max Clark => 37 Amy Jhinar => 27 Karen Robinson => 89 Bob Lewis => 29 Jackie Kitcher => 25 Jackson Adams
```

I really don't know how to figure it out. Can someone help me with the algorithm? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your example has 6 input and 6 output, therefore it doesn't seem explaining "grouping the same ones digit" part. The first step will be defining the task to do.

Comment: Yes i've 6 input and 6 output. output is list. And i just want the grouping the same values behind them. I really just needing it.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it. But i need to build this: The elements in the list are according to the last digit of the number information.
It should be added to the list dynamically in a decreasing manner.

Comment: If I'm not understanding wrong, Do you want to create and then sort the provided linked list based upon `id % 10`?

Comment: @RohanKumar that's what i'm excatly wanted. But the problem is asking to me not from small to large the amount of last digit's. I mean how many 1's how many 2's etc. And i should be order most repating last digit first, and less repeating last digit last. That literally what i'm trying to do.

Comment: You need to show what you have done so far.  Explain where you are having problems.  Can you create a list while reading the data? Should you create ten lists, one for each of the final digits?  Should the lists have control information such as head, tail and count?

Comment: @KaanDeniz At first write a function that inserts new data with the same digit sequentially. and then you can write a function that performs insertion sorting.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've built linked list. I can take values. I can count values last digit. I can add value in to the list. Only thing i couldn't that thing.

Comment: That's good. Show us.  You can't tell where the elements with a given final digit should go in the overall list until you have all the data.  You can't tell whether the entries ending 9 should go before or after the ones ending 7 until you know all the input.  So, where do you go from here?  What are your thoughts on how to evaluate the size of each group?  Do you have to keep the entries with final digit 9 in the order they were read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming this is model for your current problem. You have an `Employee` struct like this:

```c
typedef struct Employee {
    int id;
    char name[100];
    char surname[100];
} Employee;
```

Which is a part of your LinkedList node:

```c
typedef struct Node {
    Employee employee;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

I think you should be able to do it by maintaining an array of frequencies of each Node's `id % 10`. Then slightly customizing logic for your bubble sort method(Just need to compare `frequencyMap[employee.id % 10]` rather than just comparing ids.

Here is sample code:

```c
void reorderBasedOnFrequency(Node *head) {
    int frequencyMap[10] = { 0 };

    // Build array of frequencies for id mod 10`
    Node *currentNode = head;
    while (currentNode != NULL) {
        frequencyMap[currentNode->employee.id % 10]++;
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }

    // Perform Standard Bubble Sort
    bool swapped = true;
    Node *ptr1;
    Node *lptr = NULL;

    do {
        swapped = false;
        ptr1 = head;

        while (ptr1->next != lptr) {
            // Check for frequencies while sorting
            if (frequencyMap[(ptr1)->employee.id % 10] < frequencyMap[(ptr1->next)->employee.id % 10]) {
                // Swap
                swap(ptr1, ptr1->next);
                swapped = true;
            }
            ptr1 = ptr1->next;
        }
        lptr = ptr1;
    } while (swapped);
}

void swap(struct Node *a, struct Node *b) { 
    Employee temp = a->employee; 
    a->employee = b->employee; 
    b->employee = temp; 
}
```

I used it from my `main()` method like this:

```c
int main() {
    Employee employees[6] = { {47, "Max", "Clark"}, {37, "Amy", "Jhinar"}, {89, "Bob", "Davis"}, {25, "Jackson", "Adams"},
      {29, "Jackie", "Kitcher"},{27, "Karen", "Robinson"}};

    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *tail = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newNode->employee = employees[i];
        newNode->next = NULL;
        if (i == 0) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        } else {
            tail->next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
    }

    printf("Initial List: \n");
    printList(head);
    reorderBasedOnFrequency(head);
    printf("After Sorting: \n");
    printList(head);
}
```

Here is a sample run based on above code:

```
src : $ gcc linkedlistsortmodulo.c 
src : $ ./a.out 
Initial List: 
47 Max Clark  => 37 Amy Jhinar  => 89 Bob Davis  => 25 Jackson Adams  => 29 Jackie Kitcher  => 27 Karen Robinson 
After Sorting: 
47 Max Clark  => 37 Amy Jhinar  => 27 Karen Robinson  => 89 Bob Davis  => 29 Jackie Kitcher  => 25 Jackson Adams
```

**Update:**

From comments by OP, I noticed that changing Node's data is not allowed. Here is a slight variant of above solution based on the [Node Swap approach](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort-for-linked-list-by-swapping-nodes/). Here we just need to pass a `Node**` so that head gets updated if it's changed during sorting process:

```c
void reorderBasedOnFrequency(Node **head) {
  int frequencyMap[10] = { 0 };
    
  // Build array of frequencies for id mod 10`
  Node *currentNode = *head;
  int nCount = 0;
  while (currentNode != NULL) {
    frequencyMap[currentNode->employee.id % 10]++;
    currentNode = currentNode->next;
    nCount++;
  }

  // Perform Standard Bubble Sort
  bool swapped = true;
  Node **h;

  for (int i = 0; i <= nCount && swapped; i++) {
    h = head;
    swapped = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < nCount - i - 1; j++) {
      Node *p1 = *h;
      Node *p2 = p1->next;
      // Check for frequencies while sorting
      if (frequencyMap[p1->employee.id % 10] < frequencyMap[p2->employee.id % 10]) {
        // Swap
        *h = swap(p1, p2);
        swapped = true;
      }

      h = &(*h)->next;
    }
  }
}

Node* swap(struct Node *a, struct Node *b) { 
  Node *tmp = b->next;
  b->next = a;
  a->next = tmp;
  return b;
}
```

Comment: which library has got the swap function?

Comment: I had added a utility method for swapping node, I've updated my answer with that implementation.

Comment: You have `int frequencyMap[10]; for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) frequencyMap[i] = 0;` —— That's a long way of writing `int frequencyMap[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };` or even just `int frequencyMap[10] = { 0 };`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out. Sorry, I didn't know about `{ 0 }`. It looks so neat :-)

Comment: @RohanKumar I've a problem... I can't change the nodes i guess.. Can you explain it to me please :)

Comment: oh, okay. Sorting by swapping nodes instead of data can be done. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort-for-linked-list-by-swapping-nodes/ . Let me update my answer with Node swap approach

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the Node swap sorting approach as mentioned in that GeeksForGeeks link. I hope this would help :-)

Comment: @RohanKumar You've really helped me. I don't know how to thank you :))